# Forms 6i if record exists then update

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms

I need to create select statement in post_insert trigger. Is it possible if yes then how?
I want to check another table records if it exists then it will update it otherwise insert as new record. Please help.

My block code is that i want to run

```
DECLARE
 EXSIST_TYPE varchar2(50);
 EXSIST_NAME varchar2(50);
 EXSIST_COMPANY VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
 SELECT PRO_TYPE, PRO_NAME, COMPANY_NAME INTO EXSIST_TYPE, EXSIST_NAME ,EXSIST_COMPANY FROM STOCK;
IF
:PURCHASE_DETAIL.PRO_TYPE <> EXSIST_TYPE AND
:PURCHASE_DETAIL.PRO_NAME <> EXSIST_NAME AND 
:PURCHASE_DETAIL.COMPANY_NAME <> EXSIST_COMPANY THEN*/
IF
:PURCHASE.RADIO_TYPE = 'PURCHASE' THEN
INSERT INTO STOCK(
PRO_TYPE     ,
PRO_NAME     ,
COMPANY_NAME ,
QUANTITY     ,
PURCHASE_RATE,
SALE_RATE    ,
RACK_NUM     
)
VALUES
(
:PURCHASE_DETAIL.PRO_TYPE,
:PURCHASE_DETAIL.PRO_NAME,
:PURCHASE_DETAIL.COMPANY_NAME,
:PURCHASE_DETAIL.QUANTITY,
:PURCHASE_DETAIL.PRICE,
:PURCHASE_DETAIL.SALE_PRICE,
:PURCHASE_DETAIL.RACK_NUM
);
END IF;
ELSIF
:PURCHASE_DETAIL.PRO_TYPE = EXSIST_TYPE AND
:PURCHASE_DETAIL.PRO_NAME = EXSIST_NAME AND
:PURCHASE_DETAIL.COMPANY_NAME = EXSIST_NAME THEN
IF
:PURCHASE.RADIO_TYPE = 'PURCHASE' THEN
UPDATE STOCK SET
STOCK.QUANTITY = STOCK.QUANTITY+:PURCHASE_DETAIL.QUANTITY
WHERE
STOCK.PRO_TYPE = :PURCHASE_DETAIL.PRO_TYPE AND
STOCK.PRO_NAME = :PURCHASE_DETAIL.PRO_NAME AND
STOCK.COMPANY_NAME= :PURCHASE_DETAIL.COMPANY_NAME;
ELSIF
:PURCHASE.RADIO_TYPE = 'PRCH_RETURN' THEN
UPDATE STOCK SET
STOCK.QUANTITY = STOCK.QUANTITY-:PURCHASE_DETAIL.QUANTITY
WHERE
STOCK.PRO_TYPE = :PURCHASE_DETAIL.PRO_TYPE AND
STOCK.PRO_NAME = :PURCHASE_DETAIL.PRO_NAME AND
STOCK.COMPANY_NAME = :PURCHASE_DETAIL.COMPANY_NAME;
END IF;
 END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Please help this topic

Answer (score 0):

You never said what happened when you ran that code.

Anyway: requirement you mentioned ("if it exists then it will update it otherwise insert") looks like an *excellent* candidate for a MERGE statement (also called *upsert*, as a combination of UPdate and inSERT).

As Forms 6i is an old piece of software, I'm pretty much sure that MERGE can't directly be used there. However, if the underlying database is at least 9i, MERGE will work - create a stored procedure that contains MERGE, and pass form items' values as parameters.

Here's an example (taken from [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement); have a look for more examples. I'm lazy to create my own code):

```
MERGE INTO employees e
    USING hr_records h
    ON (e.id = h.emp_id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET e.address = h.address
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, address)
    VALUES (h.emp_id, h.address);
```